# How can install a new version of NPM ( 1.1.24 )?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install the latest stable version of node - Version 0.6.19 (stable).

http://blog.nodejs.org/ indicates to upgrade to NPM to 1.1.24

Is there a simple way to upgrade to this? I can't figure out how exactly to download and target this version.

The below gives me npm -v 1.0.106

```
npm upgrade npm
```

or

```
npm upgrade npm 1.1.24
```

Comment: It would be nice to know which OS you are using. When installing node from the source you always get the most current npm installed aside.

Answer (score 22):

#### Update 2 (03/11/15)

Courtesy: [whyleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927490/how-can-install-a-new-version-of-npm-1-1-24/10928235?noredirect=1#comment37366987_10928235)

> On Windows npm is installed together with node in "Program Files". Use npm install npm -g to install it in "%AppData%\npm" and delete 'npm', 'npm.cmd' files from "C:\Program Files\nodejs" dir (because your PATH is looking there first). After that you can use npm update npm -g in the future

---

According to the docs

`For windows` (it also worked on Mac for me)

To update npm, run the `npm update npm -g` command.

Also verify **[this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, right, probably OPs problem is `upgrade` instead of `update` and missing `-g` flag.

Comment: This didn't work for me on windows. The command completed without output, but the version remains the same.

Comment: On Windows npm is installed together with node in "Program Files". Use `npm install npm -g` to install it in "%AppData%\npm" and delete 'npm', 'npm.cmd' files from "C:\Program Files\nodejs" dir (because your PATH is looking there first). After that you can use `npm update npm -g` in the future.

Comment: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that worked for me was (from npm readme)

> ### Fancy Windows Install
>
> You can download a zip file from https://npmjs.org/dist/, and unpack
>   it in the same folder where node.exe lives.

In my case folder is :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs

Edit: It seams that newer versions of npm does not exist on address I wrote. I will copy paste instructions from npm git page

> You can download a zip file from https://npmjs.org/dist/, and unpack
>   it in the same folder where node.exe lives.
>
> The latest version in a zip file is 1.4.12. To upgrade to npm 2,
>   follow the Windows upgrade instructions in the npm Troubleshooting
>   Guide:
>
> https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows
>
> If that's not fancy enough for you, then you can fetch the code with
>   git, and mess with it directly.

Comment: Thanks, this is all that worked for me on Windows as well.  I guess I should have read the readme...

Comment: http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/ doesn't seem to have the latest version anymore. It has 1.4.12 while the nodejs-package has npm version 1.4.14. Whats up with that?

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu you can upgrade it using

```
sudo npm update npm -g
```

Answer (score 1):

**In windows, to install latest version of npm**

> npm install npm@latest -g

&

**In ubuntu you can use**

> sudo npm install npm@latest -g

***note: the latest version till sept 12 2016 is 
(The current stable version of npm is) 3.10.7**

check  version by running on command prompt

> npm -v

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

> Option 3: navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs with cmd.exe and then run the installation without -g:

This sovled it for me.